# Wrapper for getter methods

Tags: php, class

if I have methods like

```
function getVar1(){
  return $this->var1;
}

function getVar2(){
  return $this->var2;
}
```

and so on...

and these vars are meant to be printed on the screen, is it a good idea to create additional methods that directly print them?

like

```
   function Var1(){
     echo $this->getVar1();
   }

   function Var2(){
     echo $this->getVar2();
   }
```

or should I stick with calling echo getVar1() where I need them?

Comment: The actual malpractice here are the shallow getters themselves.

Comment: why shallow? what do you mean by that? the getters should only return a protected variable. whats wrong with that?

Comment: See http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html for some discussion. It's not overly object-oriented to have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions should do what their name implies. It's one of the core design principles. When you say `getVar()`, it does what it's meant to do: return a variable.

In your example, you are not even specifying what the function does. If you want to have a function that prints something, then call it `printVar1()` or something like that.

On the other hand, I have to agree with ThiefMaster. You can just use echo `getVar1()` instead of creating bigger classes. Especially in an interpreted language like PHP(where classes add more overhead than a compiled language).

Comment: @KingCrunch: PHP can be compiled into byte-code, but that is for specialized situations. 98% of PHP executed today is interpreted on each request.

Comment: Only without APC and even without APC is PHP-code not interpreted anymore.

Comment: "PHP-code not interpreted anymore." That is ridiculous! Why not just remove php.exe from your system and see how well your scripts run!

Comment: Ok to be fair, it compiles into byte-code on each request like you said. But it still needs to interpret before it compiles.

Comment: Ah, I see. An interpreter executes code directly from the tokens extracted from the source file. This especially means, that e.g. a function from this file, that is called multiple times, is always executed directly from the tokens, what can get slow. But PHP compiles the tokens into bytecode only once, even if the code is required more than once. Thats a huge difference. The most inefficient parts here are the IO-operations while reading the file

Answer (score 3):

Use `echo getVar1();` for this purpose. Creating functions for this is not only a waste of time but also a great way to clutter your code with useless stuff.